# How to make @Scheduled(cron=xxx) run normally when adjusting the server time to a point before the current time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have 23 methods annotated with `@Scheduled`, all of which use a cron expression. One day, I modified the server time to be several hours later and then changed it back. To my surprise, I found that all the `@Scheduled` methods had stopped working.

Initially, I thought it might be due to threads getting blocked. As a solution, I added `@Async` to all methods.

However, the situation did not seem to improve, and all `@Scheduled` methods continued to stop working even after changing the server time to a later point and then reverting it back.

To investigate further, I used VisualVM to dump the threads, and I noticed that all threads from the `timing-pool` (an Executor defined for `@Async`) were in the state of `WAITING`:

```
"timingPool-12" #66 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000216de000 nid=0x4fc4 waiting on condition [0x00000000333ce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c3791b28> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.take(SynchronousQueue.java:924)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
...
```

This led me to speculate that when using `@Scheduled` with a cron expression, adjusting the server time to a point before the current time may be the cause of the issue. To test this theory, I changed all instances of `@Scheduled(cron = xxx)` to `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = xxx)`. This time, the threads did not get blocked.

So, the question arises: Since I do need to change the server time to check some business conditions in the test environment, how can I ensure that `@Scheduled(cron = xxx)` logic runs normally even when the server time is changed especially when adjusting the time to a point before the current time?

Comment: I would say that you have to restart your application after adjusting server time.

Comment: What probably happens: for a task that is scheduled to run every hour, if it runs at 10 o'clock the scheduler determines that it needs to run again at 11 o'clock. If you now turn back the time to 6 o'clock the trigger will still fire at 11 o'clock - which means in 5 hours instead of in 1 hour.